# someone is typing css effect like the one in hangout

Tags: css

I can't really even describe what the effect's name, but its the effect appear usually on the top right of the typing input bar when the other side is typing. For example in hangout, there is one like this

[image]

I wonder how can I achieve such effect in css, in other words, those green fading effected loading effect on those 3 dots with CSS only?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some links and demos (javascript + css3)

1. [fancyInput](http://dropthebit.com/demos/fancy_input/fancyInput.html)
2. [TextInput fx](http://tympanus.net/Development/TextInputEffects/)
3. [10 js text fx](http://favbulous.com/post/788/10-javascript-text-effects)
4. [textilate](http://jschr.github.io/textillate/)
5. [typed.js](http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/)
6. [create typing effect](http://www.paulund.co.uk/create-typing-effect)

Comment: All the others are related to typing, but what I want to know is the effect of the three dots that is going to be kinda flash itself when someone else is typing..... May I have some hint on how this answer relate to the question thank you :)

Comment: @Chen, yes, sorry the effect you mention is not clear (i dont use hangout), so i just gave links to js+css text/typing effects (some are closer some not). Use as you wish